# Intersection on Google App Engine

Tags: facebook, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

When a user Facebook Connects to my site, I want to narrow down the list of the user's Facebook friends to just those that have already signed up for my website.

So I have two lists

- A list in code of a user's facebook friends (around 1000)
- A GAE table of all FB users that have signed up for my site (around 1000)

Is the most efficient way to do this to do a single query for the UIDs of all signed up FB users and do the intersection in code?

What would be the most efficient way if there were more like 10,000 FB users signed up where they couldn't all be retrieved by queries in < 30 seconds?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turn the problem around on it's head slightly. When a user logs in, fetch his friends list and store the facebook numeric ids in an list property on the user's object. (You could also use an index object... look at the [talk by Brett Slatkin](http://www.google.com/events/io/2009/sessions/BuildingScalableComplexApps.html) on doing fan-out in GAE.)

Something like

```
class User:
  friend_ids = db.ListProperty()
```

When a new user logs in, just do a query and filter on `friend_ids = :id`. This should give you a *list of existing users who are friends of your current user*. Which I believe is actually what you want.

The user query filtered on a list property will return a user if the id you're querying for is contained in the list, in case you're not familiar with that. Docs are [here](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/typesandpropertyclasses.html#ListProperty).

Comment: There's a bunch of things you need to be careful with using this approach. Two of them are: Users can have up to 5000 friends, and having an indexed list with that many items can cause problems with the datastore: timeouts, exploding indexes, etc... Furthermore, if a user just added a friend on FB and then logged into your site, they wouldn't be their friend.  You need to subscribe to real time friend updates from FB and update all the corresponding users... and be careful about timing out. (better to do it on a task queue). There's many edge cases... it's feasible, but not simple.

Comment: Yeah... I fully agree. The 5000 limit can be circumvented by using index objects, but the real time friend stream, not so easily...